# What is a criterion that a polynomial has only positive coefficients?

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$  be a  polynomial that given in implicit way, so I dont  know $a_i$. I need to know if all its coefficient are positive.

A brute force way to do it  is check out its derivative -  if 
$$
\frac{d^i f(x)}{dx^n}>0,
$$
then and  $a_i>0.$

**Question.** Is there  an elegant way to determine if the polynomial has only positive  coefficients?

Comment: You could verify that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(x)/x^n>0$

Comment: if all roots are negative and real, $P(x)=(x+a_1)(x+a_2)...(x+a_n)$ leads to all coefficients are positive.

Comment: @ Alex R  Well...$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1-x}{x^n} =\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+x}{x^n}=0.$$  How it can help  ?

Comment: Taking the derivative seems “elegant” enough to me. Why is that so undesirable?

Comment: @David K Of cource the derivative is “elegant” but I cant use it if a polynomial is given in not direct way, for example put $$f_n(x)=e^x \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x} x^n)$$

Comment: For that example, expansion of the polynomial for a few small values of $n$ suggests you will never have all positive coefficients for $n >0.$ They seem to alternate signs.

Comment: @David K Is there any statement about the "a few small values"?

Comment: I just made such a statement. I also said it **suggests** the same will be true for all positive $n$. Of course you cannot really know until you have proved it formally. But “small value” cases can sometimes give clues toward a proof.

Comment: I think $e^x \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x} x^n) = \binom n0 \frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^n-\binom n1 \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}x^n+\binom n2 \frac{d^{n-2}}{dx^{n-2}}x^n-\cdots\pm\binom nn x^n,$ demonstrable by induction, and since $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}x^n=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)x^{n-k},$ this is a polynomial with coefficients of alternating signs.